# images in a Jquery carousel aren't reacting to CSS :hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover, slider, carousel

I'm having an issue where the images in my Jquery carousel aren't reacting to :hover. Interestingly however, the final image in the series DOES react to ':hover'. I haven't the faintest clue why this might be.

I was wondering if anyone could offer any insight into this issue. Even using CSS as generalised as this doesn't yield a result.

```
li {
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 2s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;

}

li:hover {

transform: scale(1.2);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);

}
```

Here's a JSFiddle of the relevant code.

http://jsfiddle.net/robbiemissile/9aLfg2xw/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `scale` correctly? Check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.mi-slider .poster-group-current li a:hover {
 opacity: 0.7;
} 

.poster-group {
    z-index: 999;
}

.poster-group-current {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The other `.poster-group` elements were overlapping the current one. This makes your css work for me without any additional changes